# Why does this djb2 implementations loop terminate?

Tags: c

A string is terminated by a s single null byte. Since a int is bigger then an char how can the int become 0 and terminate the loop consistenly?

source : http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html

```
unsigned long
hash(unsigned char *str)
{
    unsigned long hash = 5381;
    int c;

    while (c = *str++)
        hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + c; /* hash * 33 + c */

    return hash;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading an integer from a smaller type does not preserve the bits that the smaller type didn't have; they are cleared (or set by sign-extension, for signed types).

So:

```
int x = 0xfeefd00d;
x = (char) 1;
```

leaves the value `1`, as an integer, in `x`, *not* `0xfeedf001`.

Answer (score 1):

When a variable is used in an expression together with variables of different types (like in the assignment in the loop condition), there's an [*implicit conversion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) being made. Conversions only convert between *types*, but if possible keeps the value.

So when you reach the null-terminator in `str`, it's converted ([promoted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) actually) to an `int`, keeping the value `0`. And `0` is always "false", which ends the loop.